# Jupyter Notebook: (OperationalError('disk I/O error',))

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error on running an existing Jupyter Notebook file

```
The history saving thread hit an unexpected error (OperationalError('disk I/O error',)).History will not be written to the database.
```

Never the less, the remaining code in the notebook executes properly after that. However, when I'm trying to create a new notebook file this error is not letting me create it and I get the following error:

```
Error while saving file: python_notebook_ollie/Untitled2.ipynb disk I/O error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/work/ollie/muali/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 421, in save
    self.check_and_sign(nb, path)
  File "/work/ollie/muali/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/manager.py", line 440, in check_and_sign
    self.notary.sign(nb)
  File "/work/ollie/muali/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 449, in sign
    self.store.store_signature(signature, self.algorithm)
  File "/work/ollie/muali/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 207, in store_signature
    if not self.check_signature(digest, algorithm):
  File "/work/ollie/muali/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nbformat/sign.py", line 241, in check_signature
    self.db.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: disk I/O error
[W 15:08:48.093 NotebookApp] Unexpected error while saving file: python_notebook_ollie/Untitled2.ipynb disk I/O error
[E 15:08:48.094 NotebookApp] {
  "Host": "localhost:15695",
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0",
  "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
  "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
  "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
  "Referer": "http://localhost:15695/notebooks/python_notebook_ollie/Traj_case_study.ipynb",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-Xsrftoken": "2|96ae1fed|bde68f8333dd4b46b900b02246747fa4|1520496687",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "Content-Length": "19",
  "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|96ae1fed|bde68f8333dd4b46b900b02246747fa4|1520496687; username-localhost-15695=\"2|1:0|10:1520518043|24:username-localhost-15695|44:NjE5MWZlMWIzMjdmNGE2N2FlZmQ3NmE3NzRlNmNiZmQ=|8062f4c541e5dcef0d8b4a2d7e75cc59f1d27197ac4633b9da64b7bb94aae7a4\"",
  "Connection": "keep-alive"
}
```

I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352285/ipython-operationalerror-disk-i-o-error) and deleted the history.sqlite file but, still I'm getting the disk I/O error.

Some threads on github say NFS based mount can create some problems but in the past it was working fine *until I upgraded my matplotlib package.* I've now downgraded that package but I still can't get rid of the error.

Edit: The first error displayed on the terminal while opening an .ipynb file is

```
The signatures database cannot be opened; maybe it is corrupted or  

encrypted. You may need to rerun your notebooks to ensure that they are trusted to run Javascript. The old signatures database has been renamed to ~/.local/share/jupyter/nbsignatures.db.bak and a new one has been created.
```

Comment: I found [this link](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1342) is relevant to the error. Probably, the error is occurring because sqlite locking is not working properly on NFS based system. And, I guess the trigger was when I tried to create a tunnel via my PC and thus, the same notebook file was running on 2 machines? I still don't understand how to get rid of the problem though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to make it work so I'll post what I did.
I think the cause of the problem is that SQLite locking doesn't work reliably on NFS filesystems as described in this [link](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1342).

The answer is also given there and I'll write the steps in more detail here:

Basically, one has to create a new configuration for ipython or modify an existing one. The config file named as ipython_config.py can be found in ~/.ipython/profile_default

If the config file doesn't exist by default then one can create it by typing the following in your home directory

```
ipython profile create
```

This will create the configuration files under ~/.ipython/profile_default.
Open ipython_config.py and add the following lines:

```
c = get_config() #gets the configuration
c.HistoryManager.hist_file='/tmp/ipython_hist.sqlite' #changes history file writing to tmp folder
```

Save it and re-open the kernel and it should work now. More details on modifying configurations can be found [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html)

If the configuration file already exist then just type in the terminal

```
ipython --HistoryManager.hist_file='/tmp/ipython_hist.sqlite'
```

and that should also work.

Answer (score 2):

check your home disk quota, maybe it's full.

For me, I run jupyter on a server with limited home quota. And found that as using pip day by day, `~/.cache/pip` becomes very large. Maybe I have no space to write to my home directory.

So I delete `~/.cache/pip`, then restart jupyter. everything works

Answer (score 1):

I followed the steps above and I'm not sure what went wrong, but it completely crippled Jupyter lab (`print("hello")` was taking ~30 seconds to render).

In my case, I believe the original problem was caused because the history was corrupted (`~/.ipython/profile_default/` had a file called `history-corrupt-*` with today's timestamp). I cleared the history by deleting `~/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` per Ankit's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606275/ipython-how-to-wipe-ipythons-history-selectively-securely) and that solved the problem.

N.B: I also deleted the `config` files created during the procedure above.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the issue

```
pip cache purge
```